# Why "Base Constructor" function has called twice?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Please take a look on the following example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        cout<<"Base Constructor\n";
    }

    Base(const Base& Obj)
    {
        cout<<"Base Copy Constructor\n";
    }
};
 
class Derived:public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        cout<<"Derived Constructor\n";
    }

    Derived(const Derived& Obj)
    {
        cout<<"Derived Copy Constructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d1; 

    Derived d2(d1); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Base Constructor
Derived Constructor
Base Constructor
Derived Copy Constructor
```

But I expected following output:

```
Base Constructor
Derived Constructor
Derived Copy Constructor
```

Can anyone clear my doubt as to why "Base Constructor" has called twice?

Comment: To construct `d2`'s base, why else?

Comment: Right.  You have two objects that derive from base, and both need to be constructed.

Comment: Your derived copy constructor doesn't call the base copy constructor which is maybe what you expected?

Comment: The `Derived` constructors are equivalent to `Derived() : Base() { ... }` and `Derived(const Derived& Obj) : Base() { ... }`. You can't "bypass" the construction of a base subobject.